# Kitty Terminal Icon on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, kitty

I recently installed Kitty terminal with a `curl -L https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/installer.sh | sh /dev/stdin` on Ubuntu 23.04, and I wanted to change the icon to this: https://github.com/samholmes/whiskers but instruction is unclear about this, how can I do this?

I created a desktop entry using the instructions:

```
ln -sf ~/.local/kitty.app/bin/kitty ~/.local/kitty.app/bin/kitten ~/.local/bin/
cp ~/.local/kitty.app/share/applications/kitty.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
cp ~/.local/kitty.app/share/applications/kitty-open.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
sed -i "s|Icon=kitty|Icon=/home/$USER/.local/kitty.app/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/kitty.png|g" ~/.local/share/applications/kitty*.desktop
sed -i "s|Exec=kitty|Exec=/home/$USER/.local/kitty.app/bin/kitty|g" ~/.local/share/applications/kitty*.desktop
```

So I had the idea of changing the path of `Icon=/home/$USER/.local/kitty.app/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/kitty.png` in entry, but nothing happened, what did I miss?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only, so OS support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You can ask on [ubuntu.se] instead, but first please take [their tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) and check out [their How to Ask page](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). BTW there's also [unix.se].